# I can’t write an algorithm to the side that guesses numbers using the aiogram module

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to write a telegram bot using a module that will guess numbers, but when writing the bot itself, I came across a problem. I can’t interpret the algorithm I wrote for the aiogram module, or rather, I can’t make the second input of the number in the 'while' itself, because after I enter the number I endlessly output the result of only one 'if'. The algorithm that I tried to interpret below.

```
import random
win = False
randnum = random.randint(1,100)
tr = 0
print(randnum)
while win != True:
    try:
        number = int(input())
        if number > 100 or number < 1:
            print('Please enter a number between 1 and 100')
            tr += 1
        elif  number < randnum:
            print('This number is less than the guessed, please try again.')
            tr += 1
        elif number > randnum:
            print('This number is greater than the guessed, please try again.')
            tr += 1
        elif number == randnum:
            print(f'Congratulations, you guessed right. You spent {tr} attempts on this')
            win = True
            tr = 0
    except:
        print('This is not a number. Try again')
        tr += 1
```

Maybe someone also faced this problem and knows how to solve it?

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Играть")
async def game(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Number guesses')
    win = False
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    tr = 0
    print(number)
    while win != True:
        try:
            @dp.message_handler()
            async def game(message: types.Message):
                if int(message.text) > 100 or int(message.text) < 1:
                    await message.reply('Please enter a number between 1 and 100.')
                    tr += 1
                elif int(message.text) < number:
                    await message.reply('This number is less than the guessed, please try again.')
                    tr += 1
                elif int(message.text) > number:
                    await message.reply('This number is greater than the guessed, please try again.')
                    tr += 1
                elif int(message.text) == number:
                    await message.reply(f'Congratulations, you guessed right. You spent {tr} attempts on this')
                    win = True
                    tr = 0
        except:
            await message.reply('This is not a number. Try again')
            tr += 1
```

Comment: For me it works fine. Maybe it's got something to do with how you call the script?

Comment: @Justlearnedit maybe I’m just working with this module not so long ago. How exactly did you do this?

Comment: I copied the code into a file and ran it trough the terminal with `python3 nums.py`.

Comment: @Justlearnedit did you run this code? Just when I rewrote this algorithm for a bot and it doesn’t work for me, here is the code.